# Empty email body with action mailer and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, actionmailer

I have one test case where i want to test the body of the email:

```
last_email.to.should include(user.email)
last_email.body.should match(user.email)
```

But the body is always empty when i run rspec:

```
 Failure/Error: last_email.body.encoded.should match(user.email)
   expected "" to match "louise.denis@thomas.eu"
```

the sender/recipients/subject fields are all OKs. How can I access the body of the email (encoded in HTML)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad. The mailer view folder name was mispelled, that's why the body was empty...

Comment: Did you found a way to test this?